# Can't find any info on Python's read() method (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

I'm trying to learn Python by going through Zed Shaw's "Learn Python the hard way" and I'm stuck at what may seem as a very trivial thing. I'm unable to find any info on the .read() method. This is what he says in the book:

> Run pydoc file and scroll down until you see the .read() command (method/function).
>   See all the other ones you can use? Skip the ones that have __ (two underscores) in front
>   because those are junk. Try some of the other commands.

If I call `python -m pydoc` I only get a very short list of information regarding `pydoc.py`, `pydoc.py -k`, `pydoc.py -p`, `pydoc.py -g`, and `pydoc.py -w`

When I tried calling `python -m pydoc read` I got the following message:

> no Python documentation found for 'read'

Is the `.read` method embedded in Python by default or does it have to be imported first? I should note that I'm using Powershell on Windows 7. What could be the problem here?

Comment: You could just use the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: Did you run `pydoc file` like it says? Because `read` is in there.

Comment: *"Run pydoc file"* - `python -m pydoc file`!

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, my bad. I need to be more cognizant of details and avoid stupid mistakes like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` is a method on file objects. Use:

```
python -m pydoc file
```

to get the documentation for file objects. Note that this is exactly what the book told you to do, but it appears you left of the `file` argument.

Alternatively, ask for just the method:

```
python -m pydoc file.read
```

The official documentation, however, is far richer and useful. See the documentation on [*File Objects*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) for example.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try not to make dumb mistakes like that again.

Answer (score 2):

Note the formatting in [Exercise 15](http://lpthw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ex15/):

> 6. Run `pydoc file` and scroll down until you see the `read()` command (method/function)...

This is **not accidental**; the command you need is right there:

```
python -m pydoc file
              # ^ note argument
```

Comment: Yep, just saw people explain it in the comments. Embarrassing. Thanks.